# Problem with including Eigen library in Clion CMake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, eigen

I have a problem with the Eigen library. I use Clion on Linux and my project can't find the Eigen library (I have it in a folder on my desktop).

I have CMake in two configurations:

First:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(TestFEM)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(EIGEN_DIR "~/Desktop/eigen-3.3.7")
include_directories(${EIGEN_DIR})

add_executable(TestFEM main.cpp FEM/FEM.cpp FEM/FEM.h)
```

And second:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(TestFEM)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(TestFEM main.cpp FEM/FEM.cpp FEM/FEM.h)
```

All the time, I have an error like this:

```
fatal error: Eigen\Dense: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, try using the **full** path to the Eigen directory (without `~`).

```
set(EIGEN_DIR "/home/xxxx/Desktop/eigen-3.3.7")
include_directories(${EIGEN_DIR})
```

Also, check to be sure that path actually contains `Eigen/Dense`, so the full file path would be:

```
/home/xxxx/Desktop/eigen-3.3.7/Eigen/Dense
```

A better approach would be to use CMake to **verify** that path exists before using it:

```
set(EIGEN_DIR "/home/xxxx/Desktop/eigen-3.3.7")
if(NOT EXISTS ${EIGEN_DIR})
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Please check that the set Eigen directory is valid!")
endif()
include_directories(${EIGEN_DIR})
```

But you can be even more safe by verifying you are in the correct location *within* the Eigen repository by using [`find_path()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/find_path.html). The Eigen repository has a dummy file `signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library` that you can use to verify you indeed found Eigen's top-level directory. Just use the `PATHS` clause to tell CMake where to look:

```
find_path(EIGEN_DIR NAMES signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library
    PATHS
    /home/xxxx/Desktop/eigen-3.3.7
    PATH_SUFFIXES eigen3 eigen
)
include_directories(${EIGEN_DIR})
```